# How to get Value from Selected Option in Laravel from 2 different table in database

Tags: php, laravel, html-select

I want to get the Value of it to insert it into my Games table in database. But I have to show the name of genre from the Genres table in database.

View:

```
<select name="genreid">
                    @foreach($genres as $genre)
                        <option value="{{ $genre->genreid }}"> {{ $genre->genre }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
```

Controller:

```
public function insertgame(Request $request){

        $this -> validate($request, array(
                'gamename' => 'required|min:3',
                'price' => 'required|int|min:1',
                'genre' => 'required',
                'releaseddate' => 'required|date',
                'picture' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
        ));


        $gamename = $request->input('gamename');
        $genreid = $request->input('genreid');
        $price = $request->input('price');
        $releaseddate = Carbon::parse($request->input('releaseddate'));
        $picture = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();

        $data=array('gamename' => $gamename, 'genreid'=>$genreid, 'price'=>$price,'releaseddate'=>$releaseddate,'picture'=>$picture );

        DB::table('games')->insert($data);

        return redirect('managegame');

    }
```

Comment: You're passing `$value` to view, but `$value` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Please show results of `{{ dd($genres) }}`

Comment: sorry the 'value'=>$value is not included, i forgot to erase it after i test some code

Comment: Collection {#207 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => Genres {#208 ▶}
    1 => Genres {#209 ▶}
    2 => Genres {#210 ▶}
    3 => Genres {#211 ▶}
    4 => Genres {#212 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: @SteveRuru please update your answer with select element HTML generated by `@foreach`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin updated

Comment: inside 0=>Genres
#items: array:5 [▼
    0 => Genres {#208 ▼
      #primaryKey: "genreid"
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:2 [▶]
      #original: array:2 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }

Comment: @SteveRuru no, I mean look into the source code in a browser and copy paste HTML generated by `@foreach`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said it works for you if you use this HTML:

```
<select name="genre">
    <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
    <option value="Action">Sports</option>
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
    <option value="Simulation">Simulation</option>
</select>
```

In this case, to use proper data format, change this:

```
<option value="{{ $genre->genreid }}">{{ $genre->genre }}</option>
```

To:

```
<option value="{{ $genre->genre }}">{{ $genre->genre }}</option>
```

Comment: thank you, i've tried your answer but it's still error like before.
the error started when i put @foreach to get data from DB.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'genre' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `games` (`gamename`, `genre`, `price`, `releaseddate`, `picture`) values (Test, Sports, 100, 2009-09-09 00:00:00, example.jpg))

Comment: @SteveRuru this error is not related to the original question. The error says you do not have `genre` column in the `games` table. You get this error when you're trying to insert the data with `DB::table('games')->insert($data);`.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
@foreach($game->genres as $genre)
{
  <option value='{{$genre->id}}' {{$game->genre ==$genre->id ? 'selected' :' '> {{$genre->name}} </option>
 }
```

Comment: do you mean like this?
<option value="{{$genre->id}} {{$game->genre ==$genre->id ? 'selected'}}"> {{$genre->name}} </option>

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer!

I just changed

'genre' => 'required',

to

'genreid' => 'integer|required',

LOL Thanks all